# React : Aggrid highlight the row on row click

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

- My requirement is row selection should be with checkboxes, and row click should highlight the row (on row click, the checkbox should not be selected).
- Currently clicking on the row all rows are getting highlighted instead of specific row clicked.
  I have attached a "**plnkr.co/edit/HUdG7fgHur2WQNLb?open=index.jsx&preview**". Any suggestions will be appreciated.